# AWS Route53 search/sort domains by expiration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Is there any way on AWS Route53 search/sort domains by expiration, or export a list of domains with expiration date so I can sort them?  We have pages of domains, and I need to better manage them with our customers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cli to list all domains. It outputs json which includes the expiry date.

`aws route53domains list-domains`

If you have more than 100 domains you'll need to make multiple calls passing a token from the response into the next request.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53domains/list-domains.html